# How I could remove leading zeros in string C# WPF

Tags: c#, string

After I convert a decimal value  `salePr` to string, using following code:

```
decimal salePr;
string salePrStr;
...
salePrStr = (salePr).ToString("0000.00");
'''
```

I'd like to get rid of leading zeros (in case result is <1000).

What is right and the best way to do this operation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So why have you explicitly included them? Just use a format string of `0.00`.

Comment: Wow, it works! Didn't know. Thanks a lot, I feel a little stupid.

Answer (score 6):

You could use trimstart to remove the leading zeros.

```
salePrStr = (salePr).ToString("0000.00").TrimStart(Convert.ToChar("0"));
```

Comment: +1 Yes I tried and it works. Thanks for sharing, this is direct answer to my question and now I will know how to do this, but the real my problem was in incerting these zeros without necessity. Thanks!

Comment: It answered the question, but not in the best way.  That's why I gave +1 to David M for the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to display currency, if you want to display it as currency, try `salePrStr = String.Format("{0:C}", salePr)` otherwise use the format `0.00`

Answer (score 3):

```
salePrStr = (salePr).ToString("###0.00");
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are probably what you're looking for. *If*, for some reason, however, you actually want to *keep* the original strings (with leading zeroes), you can then write:

```
string salePrStr = salePr.ToString("0000.00");
string salePrStrShort = salePrStr.TrimStart('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

salePrStr = (salePr).ToString("N2");

That would make 1000.10 show as
1,000.10

and make 45.2305 show as
45.23

Just testing it in c#